# Can connect to website through direct external ip adress, cannot through domain

Tags: apache, web-hosting, cloudflare

I have a raspberry pi 4 running a tomcat server hosting my website. Right now it's blank, and I wanted to do connection tests on it before starting to build it. I am doing this to keep costs minimal and to be able to do other things with it later. However, as you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhnDI.png), I thought this was the way to set it up, but I get a 522 every time I try to connect to it. (I have IP blurred as it is my home IP). But, when I connect to the IP address directly, even through another wifi network, the page loads. Cloudflare has worked in the past when I was hosting on Google Firebase for a little bit, but once I switched to the pi, it stopped.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Name resolution seems to not be working.  What happens when you do `nslookup YOURDOMAIN` ?  This has to work first and foremost.  Note that there could be a delay for the resolution to spread.  One test you could do is define the name in your local hosts file (/etc/hosts) to test.  It it works, you will know it is a DNS issue 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudflare 522 errors are commonly caused by a wrong SSL configuration for your domain.

If you do not have HTTPS enabled locally, then you need to use the `Flexible` SSL mode. If you have HTTPS enabled then you need to switch to `Full` mode.

1. Choose the domain and go to the **SSL/TLS** tab
2. Select the right SSL mode depending on your setup and validate if it works.

[image]

You could have been using a different configuration when you were with Google.

See this link for more info: https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes